# SCSS is "&" necessary for targeting nested children?

Tags: sass

I'm trying to get a handle on what the & sign does when using it BEFORE a nested element. I using it after targets the parent, but before it seems unnecessary.

This...

```
ul {
  list - style: none;
  text - align: left; 
  & li {
    margin - bottom: 17 px;
  }
}
```

Seems to compile to the same as this...

```
ul {
  list - style: none;
  text - align: left;
  li {
    margin - bottom: 17 px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to always. It depends on the context. The `&` symbol refers to the current element scope, and is generally used for adding pseudo selectors like `:hover`, `focus` etc:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Whereas omitting the `&` before the `:` will result in a wrong selector:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;

  :hover {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

Compiles down to:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a :hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Which doesn't work as intended. You can try out different variations at http://www.sassmeister.com/ without any setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it should be the same. & is usually used for creating complex class names, when using class naming methodology such as BEM. For example to get class "ul_styled", you can use

```css
ul {
  somestyle...
  &_styled {
    somestyle...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&`-operator in sass is not meant to do what you suppose it to do - it is just for your convenience that is does not just explode.

You can use to combine multiple attributes (classes, id etc.) to reduce the loc like this:

```
.a {
    color: white;
    &.b {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

becomes this when compiled:

```
.a {
    color: white;
}
.a.b {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Read more in this article: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Answer (score 0):

actually the `&` sign is a placeholder for the element one level higher in the CSS, so I think your two examples should not be exactly the same. But since both address *all* `li` elements inside a `ul` (also one or two levels down), both will have the same effect on any submenu `li`s